# How to bypass authorization using XMLHttpRequest header?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to access a diagram (the type of url is image), which require authorization, and display it in fancybox. So I tried to use XMLHttpRequest to send authorization in header first and access this url again since the authorization has already bypassed in cache, that's why I set async to false. Here is my code:

```
function showDiagram(row){
    var authCode = $("#authCode").text();
    var header = "basic" + authCode;
    console.log("In show diagram");
    var id = row.children().eq(6).text();
    openURL = restURL + "/service/runtime/process-instances/" + id + "/diagram";
    console.log(openURL);
    var xhr
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhr.open("GET", openURL, false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authCode);
    xhr.send();
    console.log(xhr.status);
    if(xhr.status==200){
        callFancybox(openURL);
    }else{
        alert("The diagram cannot be shown!");
    }
}
```

However, I have met two different error situations.

1. The browser still ask me to enter username and password when I access the url for the first time, at the same time, console print out status = 200 and fancybox has already popped up, if I refuse to enter password, a GET 401(Unauthorized) error will be returned. If I entered the password, the diagram will show in fancybox and it will work well for all other url I am trying access.
2. Console print out status = 200 and the fancybox will pop and show "The requested content cannot be loaded.
   Please try again later." And a GET 401(Unauthorized) error will be returned.

Why this happening? What should I do to bypass auto login and display the url in fancybox? Thank you very much for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

You're not specifying what is on the server side, and the problem is there. You must modify your server so that it supports your header authentication. With your current implementation the server is ignoring the headers, and so it's challenging you to indentify in a different way.

Besides you'r not sending any kind of credentials or whatever. You must add headers with that information.

Comment: Thank you! I have many similar link to click, why all others will work well if I input authorization once?

Comment: Usually, once you get authenticated, and authorized, the server issues a session cookie to the browser which is sent back to the server with every request, so that the server knows that the browser session is already auithenticated. If you open ypur browser's console and examine the requests you'll probably find this cookie. I cannot gove the exact details, because that depends on the server's technology. Anyway, your speaking about two different questions: authentication (who you are) and authorization (what you can do). It's important to understand they are not the same thing